# My question is about the warp of time and space near black holes

Tags: black-hole, singularity, wormhole

I have seen some recent articles indicating that there might not be a singularity at the center of black hole at all<sup>1</sup>. Have further heard commentary about black holes that spin incredibly fast.

I was wondering if this spin could actually provide enough centrifugal force to keep all of the mass in the Event Horizon of larger and faster spinning black holes. If this is the case can we use the rotation of the black hole to increase your mass to such an extent that you could Warp or Wormhole through the Event Horizon if any of this is true wouldn't a black hole have the thinnest Event Horizon near its poles as opposed to at its rotational Horizon.

What little research I've done because I'm not an astrophysicist has led me to the conclusion that warping through a solid object would probably be a very bad idea whereas a wormhole might actually provide an opportunity. Of course this is theoretical but we technically can't detect a singularity because the Event Horizon makes it impossible. Is this theoretically possible?

---

<sup>1</sup> Science News [Study finds that black hole inner horizons can be charged or discharged](https://phys.org/news/2022-01-black-hole-horizons-discharged.html#:%7E:text=If%20a%20black%20hole%20is,therefore%20called%20the%20inner%20horizon.%22) which links to Klein, Zahn and  Hollands (2021) PRL
[Quantum (Dis)Charge of Black Hole Interiors](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.127.231301)

> The theory of general relativity unites space and time into the concept of spacetime and describes gravity as a bending of that spacetime," Christiane Klein, one of the researchers who carried out the study, told Phys.org. "One of its most prominent predictions are black holes (i.e., regions of the spacetime from which even light cannot escape). If a black hole is electrically charged or rotating, its interior has an interesting feature: Inside the black hole, there is a surface with properties resembling those of the event horizon (i.e., the outer edge) of the black hole. It is therefore called the inner horizon.

Comment: "I have seen some recent articles"  You must link to these articles or your question is not clear.

Comment: Also do the words "Kerr metric" mean anything to you?

Comment: What does *"thinnest Event Horizon"* mean. An event horizon is a mathematical surface, it has zero thickness.

Comment: https://phys.org/news/2022-01-black-hole-horizons-discharged.html#:~:text=If%20a%20black%20hole%20is,therefore%20called%20the%20inner%20horizon.%22.     this is the link to the article to which I refer

Comment: https://phys.org/news/2022-01-black-hole-horizons-discharged.html#:~:text=If%20a%20black%20hole%20is,therefore%20called%20the%20inner%20horizon.%22

Comment: I don't think this question is focused enough to be answered on this site.  If you are interested in these topics, I can recommend the book "Black Holes and Time Warps" by Kip Thorne (theoretical physicist who was technical consultant on Interstellar)

Comment: The linked article is about charged black holes.  But your question is about rotating black holes.  The linked article doesn't say "there might not be a singularity", but is about interesting effects at the inner event horizon.  There is nothing in the article about "warping" or "wormholes".  Please give more details about what you have been reading concerning rotating black holes.

Comment: "Black Holes and Time Warps" by Kip Thorne I should look into that, thank you. James K you are correct. I can look up other articles and post them so that you can look into them as well if you like. As it turns out however wormholes apparently have a problem with the gravity that they themselves generate may cause them to collapse on themselves much less trying to send them through the tremendous gravity of a black hole but I thank you for your response anyway.